# Is there a mean with Scikit learn, to do a stratified split based on several variables?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, training-data

I'm working on a dataframe, and I noticed that 3 variables were really important to predict the labels. So I want to split my dataframe in a test and train set, but not with a random split, with a stratified split based on this 3 variables (to keep the same distribution in the train set than in the original dataframe). The function `StratifiedShuffleSplit` has been created to handle labels so with it I can only specify one variable not the three, if I'm not wrong. Anyone can help me ? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

This cross-validation object is a merge of StratifiedKFold and ShuffleSplit, which returns stratified randomized folds. The folds are made by preserving the percentage of samples for each class.

Note: like the ShuffleSplit strategy, stratified random splits do not guarantee that all folds will be different, although this is still very likely for sizeable datasets.

```
>>> StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, random_state=0, ...)
>>> for train_index, test_index in sss.split(X, y):
...    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
...    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
...    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```